# Show that $GL_n(R) =SL_n(R) \rtimes R^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that $GL_n(R) =SL_n(R) \rtimes R^{\times}$, where $ : R^{\times} \to Aut(SL_n(R))$ is injective. Prove that if n is odd, then $GL_n(R) =SL_n(R) \times R^{\times}$.

I kinda see how it might happen: $SL$ is a normal subgroup and $R^{\times}$ can be a diagonal matrix with identity element on diagonal. But I don't see how n is odd or even will matter. I don't know anything about "splitting" etc. that are beyond semidirect product--this is why I asked in this post.

Comment: I presume $R=\Bbb R$, not any general commutative ring.

Comment: As you say you can think of $\Bbb R^\times$ as the matrices $\pmatrix{a&&&\\&1&&\\&&1&\\&&&&\cdots}$. The catch is that this subgroup is not normal.

Comment: If $n$ is odd,  for any invertible matrix $A$,  $d = \det(A)$ has a real $n$-th root.   It follows that $A$ is the product of an element of  SL and a  $D = d^{1/n} I$.

Comment: @fredgoodman Suppose what you said are true, we only proved that $GL \subseteq SL_n(R) R^{\times}$ right? Why $SL_n(R) R^{\times}=SL_n(R) \times R^{\times}$?

Comment: Indeed, there is still something to do.  I only  indicated why the parity of $n$ matters.  Work on the question, I think you can solve it.

Comment: The only way I know how is to show $R^{\times}$ is normal. But I can't think of a way to show it. It'd appreciate it if you can offer some hints

Comment: In the odd case, you choose your copy of $R^\times$ to be multiples of the identity matrix.  That is evidently a normal subgroup.